# react testing library with mock service worker should be able to dynamically return response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, msw

I have a form which i am trying to test and attached the sample test.

1. In the form, it initially updates with get request.
2. initially the checkbox https is not checked and thats asserted in
   the test with false. its assigned to variable button1
3. when the save button is pressed if you read the test at the bottom, there will be a put request fired and UI is expected to be updated with the get request
4. this time the response data property named protocol is changed.
5. and i expect my last statement to succeed as its expected the value sent in the protocol

Question:

**How can i send response dynamically based on the request?**

- Intially the protocol value is 'http', which renders the UI
  appropriately.
- second time when the get request is fired, i want a different response.
  the different response is actaully what is received in the put request.

```js
it('should update form and return expect behavior behavior on UI', async () => {
  server.use(
    rest.get(`*/request-to-get-data-and-show on UI`, (_req, res, ctx) => {
      return res.once(
        ctx.delay(2000),
        ctx.status(200),
        ctx.json({
          detail: 'ok',
          protocol:"http",
          ip: 'fvackq.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com',
          port: 80,
        })
      );
    }),
    rest.put(`*/request-to-update-db`, (_req, res, ctx) => {
      const data = _req.body as {
        ip: string;
        port: number;
        protocol: string;
      };
      // console.log('protocol put request',data);
      expect(data.protocol).toEqual('https')
      return res(ctx.delay(2000), ctx.status(200));
    })
  );
  
  render(<Settings />);
  const button1 = await screen.findByRole('radio', { name: 'Https', checked: false })
  
  fireEvent.click(button1, { target: { checked: true } })

  await screen.findByRole('radio', { name: 'Https',checked: true })

  const saveButton = screen.getByRole('button', {
    name: /save/i
  })
  
  fireEvent.click(saveButton);

  await  screen.findByRole('radio', { name: 'Https', checked: true })

},10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with msw. You should be able to use res.once multiple times and it should go in order. Try that:

```
server.use(
    rest.get(`*/request-to-get-data-and-show on UI`, (_req, res, ctx) => {
      return res.once(
        ctx.delay(2000),
        ctx.status(200),
        ctx.json({
          detail: 'ok',
          protocol:"http",
          ip: 'fvackq.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com',
          port: 80,
        })
      );
    }),
rest.get(`*/request-to-get-data-and-show on UI`, (_req, res, ctx) => {
      return res.once(
        ctx.delay(2000),
        ctx.status(200),
        ctx.json({whatever new response you want })
      );
    }),
    rest.put(`*/request-to-update-db`, (_req, res, ctx) => {
      const data = _req.body as {
        ip: string;
        port: number;
        protocol: string;
      };
      // console.log('protocol put request',data);
      expect(data.protocol).toEqual('https')
      return res(ctx.delay(2000), ctx.status(200));
    })
  );
```